# Ember function: Array item push and remove

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I have an ember function that is continuing the sequence of 2^x where X is the length of the array.

```
//sequence of ^2: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc...
this.set("numSeq", Ember.Array([1, 2, 4]));
```

when i push a button I update the sequence using the `update` function

```
update: function() {
    var numSeq = this.get("numSeq");
    let Sqlength = numSeq.length;
    let node = Math.pow(2, Sqlength);
    const nodeMax = Math.pow(2, 20);
    if (node >= nodeMax) {
        this.initializeSequence();
    } else if (Sqlength >= 10) {
        sequence.pushObject(node);
        let smallFry = sequence[0];
        sequence.removeObject(smallFry);

    } else {
        sequence.pushObject(node);
    }
}
```

there are two restrictions to the update function, when  a new array input exceeds 2^20 we reset the array, and when the length is greater than 10 we remove the smallest element and still add the new node.

My issue comes when trying to push new objects to array and remove the bottom most element, any method I have used to far `slice`,`removeat`,`removeobject`,  it "freezes" the array and just adds the last element not the new node

(example after pressing the button 12 times
[1,2,4,...,512,1024,1024,1024]

no errors so i believe this my fault and a misunderstanding of concepts

Answer (score 0):

My error was using the length as the exponent, I just had to use the currentNode*2 to get the next node, not use the length

keeping length at ten always gave me 1024 which is why it would never grow! my own failure but figured it out